# What resistance would I need?

Tags: pcb, resistors, raspberry-pi, resistance

I'm kinda new to PCB design, but here we go:

I've created a simple sub-pump water level monitor and it uses a constant 5V from a MOSFET. In the end, it's all monitored by a raspberry pi and I know if I put 5V straight into a GPIO pin as input, that's going to kill the pi very fast so i'm wondering if anybody knows an appropriate resistor to use for this.

[image: PCB Schematic]

Comment: Can you provide a schematic? CTRL+M when you edit post for schematic editor. From the sounds of it, you need a clamp diode and resistor, not just a resistor.

Comment: Sure but just letting you know it's a Eagle File

Comment: Use the Windows Snipping  tool it then and copy paste to the post.

Comment: It's a very simple design as you can tell

Comment: 10K is also too high. Your LEDs get no current. What is the LED forward voltage drop?

Comment: The Pads Labeled 1, 2, 3, 4 will be attached to a 4 point float switch and the supply for those 4 points will be 5V, the nets that are labeled the same share a connection as on the pin headers so they would have 5V heading into the raspberry pi

Comment: Oh, the Pi pins aren't the npn base. You are using the NPNs as open collector outputs to feed the pins? Your NPNs are upside down and your LED resistors are too high. You need base resistors for your float switch too. Then we can worry about 5V on the pins.

Comment: Min = 2.8 Max = 3.5 Voltage Drop

Comment: Yes that is exactly what is happening here

Comment: Then we can worry about 5V LED on the pins (the float switch isn't the problem, it never makes it to the RPi pins); It is the LED supply you need to worry about. That is a little more involved.

Comment: With 2.8V worst case LED voltage drop, that is 5V-2.8V = 2.2V of excess voltage we need to drop across the LED resistor. If you want 10mA LED current, then I = V/R = 2.2V/10mA = 220 ohms. This is for LEDs only, The RPi pins are not protected from 5V yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just some minor corrections

[image]

Murphy's Law.

If anything can be backwards, it will be.

Comment: Not really clear where you would hook up the MCU to this. It is a board using 3.3V, not 5V. And the LED forward voltage could be anything. Using a LED in series with the driving voltage is fishy overall. I can't make any sense of the original schematic.

Comment: The input can be any logic level  and output DC should not much more than LED so it could be a 12V string or a 3 LEDs +R or 5V 1 LED+R .. Just make Base current > 5% of LED current by choosing base R. THe question lacks experience